# change hexadecimal range in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ranges in hexadecimals like below.

```
range = "80000000-d554ffff"
range = "d5550000-2aa9ffff"
range = "2aaa0000-7fffffff"
```

I don't understand how to change above ranges in percentage.

Answer must be like - 50%, 25% ,25% not exactly this. answer as per data.

> If min=80000000 and max=7fffffff then?

https://jsfiddle.net/amitkushwaha1710/wk4786tr/

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to increase or decrease the range by a certain percentage?

Comment: yes you are right percentage as per data I said I gave just as example

Comment: I don't see how the first answer would be -30% when it's a -40% decrease or 66% increase between the values (`3579117567` to `2147483648`)

Comment: Please explain precisely what is the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the decimal values, take the delta and get the percent value.

```js
var ranges = ["80000000-d554ffff", "d5550000-2aa9ffff", "2aaa0000-7fffffff"],
    result = ranges.map(s => {
        var [l, r] = s.split('-').map(v => parseInt(v, 16));
        return (r - l) * 100 / l;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: percentage is out of 100 and your answer crossed 100.

Comment: it depends on the total value and the other value. if you have a total of 80 and the other is 240, then you get 200%, because 80 * 200 / 100 is 160 and the result is 240.